# Google DFP on infinite scroll (jQuery DFP + Ajax Load More)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, infinite-scroll, google-dfp

I have a infinite scroll page and I wish to display ads in every single one of them, using DFP.

I'm using [jQuery DFP](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js) to call my DFP ads. Here's the regular call that displays an ad in my page:

```
$.dfp({
    dfpID: 'xxxx',
    enableSingleRequest: 'false'
});
```

My infinite scroll script ([Ajax Load More](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/add-ons/previous-post/) plugin for WordPress) offers me callback function that is dispatched after every successful query.

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.almComplete = function(alm){
    console.log("Ajax Load More Complete!");
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The code that I came up to is this one, that, according to the console.log, is loaded. BUT the ads are not being shown in subsequent pages that are loaded through ajax, just the first one.

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.almComplete = function(alm){
    console.log("Ajax Load More Complete!");
    $.dfp({
        dfpID: 'xxxx',
    enableSingleRequest: 'false'
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Any help? :)